# Rails assets precompile fails with exit code 1 during Docker build on Railway

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to deploy my Ruby on Rails application on Railway, but the deployment fails during the bundle exec rake assets:precompile step with exit code 1. Here's the error message I'm getting:

```
ERROR: failed to solve: process "/bin/bash -ol pipefail -c bundle exec rake assets:precompile" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

I've also checked the logs generated by the rake assets:precompile command with the --trace option, but there are no specific error messages that can help me identify the problem.

Does anyone have any idea what might be causing this issue and how I can resolve it on Railway? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Update: I have fixed the first issue

Next error i am getting is:

```
config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

* development - set it to false

* test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)

* production - set it to true

Exiting

bundler: failed to load command: bin/rails (bin/rails)

/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-3.2.2/gems/activerecord-7.0.8/lib/active_record/database_configurations.rb:177:in `resolve_symbol_connection': The `environment` database is not configured for the `environment` environment. (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)

Available database configurations are:

default

development

test

production
```

Comment: Did you try running the `assets:precompile` task locally? What happened when you did?

Comment: rails assets:precompile
rails aborted!
ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage: ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage (ActiveSupport::MessageEncryptor::InvalidMessage)
/home/ebrookes/code/Harradine-Property/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'

Caused by:
OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError: OpenSSL::Cipher::CipherError
/home/ebrookes/code/Harradine-Property/config/environment.rb:5:in `<main>'
Tasks: TOP => environment
(See full trace by running task with --trace) that's the error i am getting @spickermann

Comment: Seems like the setup is missing a secret key for the application's [`MessageEncryptor`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/MessageEncryptor.html) configuration. Or the configured key is invalid.

Comment: Yeah i have just found that out :( i have fixed it now although the deployment is still crashing. But thankyou for your help anyways @spickermann

Comment: @spickermann this is the error i am getting now config.eager_load is set to nil. Please update your config/environments/*.rb files accordingly:

* development - set it to false

* test - set it to false (unless you use a tool that preloads your test environment)

* production - set it to true

Comment: Try setting `eager_load` to `true` temporarily in your development environment. Or to run `assets:precompile` with `RAILS_ENV=production` on your local machine. Note that all these steps are only temporarily. The goal is to run the `assets:precompile` task that is failing on production locally, and to observe what error it raises. Once you got the error in the assets fixed, the changes to your configuration should be reverted again.

Comment: Thankyou very much for your help i shall try this and let you know @spickermann